# What is causing this plugin to fail?

Tags: linux

I'm trying to implement NetApp monitoring in our Nagios environment. When I run the command

```
perl /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_netapp_ontap.pl -n <IP_ADDRESS> -u sysrb7 -p <password>
```

I get

```
Failed test query: NaServer::parse_xml - Error in parsing xml:
syntax error at line 1, column 49, byte 49:
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
================================================^
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
 at /usr/lib64/perl5/XML/Parser.pm line 187
```

Any idea what the parser is not liking? Despite being a Linux admin, I don't speak fluent Perl. Any help will be great.

Answer (score 0):

This error seems to indicate that it doesn't like the quotation mark near the end of the line on line 1 of the document it was parsing and that it appears to be parsing it as XML. Is the document XML? Try to get it manually with wget or curl to see what is being retrieved.

Based on your post, it really looks like you hit a page that doesn't exist (`404 Not Found`) and the response was HTML. Not what the script was expecting.

If you don't know the URL, check check_netapp_ontap.pl.

You can goto line 187 of /usr/lib64/perl5/XML/Parser.pm to see exactly what the perl script was trying to do. This is the XML module on your system, not actually part of the netapp script.

Debugging, though probably not necessary:

You can debug perl scripts with `perl -d script.pl`. Once the debugger starts you can do various things or just keep hitting `n` to go line by line.

Resources:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8923266/how-to-run-through-a-perl-program-step-by-step
http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/05/perl-debugger/